# Why are constructors adding overhead compared to aggregate initialization?

Tags: c++, constructor, initialization

I noticed that assembly output grew slightly when adding a constructor to a type that was previously aggregate. Take this example.

```c++
struct Foo1 {
  std::string value;
};

struct Foo2 {
  Foo2() = default;
  Foo2(auto&& x) : value { std::forward<decltype(x)>(x) }
  {}
  std::string value;
};
```

You can see here (https://quick-bench.com/q/IeysMn4GPne95yrRTl1Fl_z2IXg) that the code size not only grows but there is a notable performance penalty.

Comment: Aggregates result in less objects during initialization, since their members can be initialized directly under guaranteed copy-elision. A c'tor needs an extra object to bind a reference to. Also, since you are creating small strings, SSO means your "moves" aren't giving you any benefit compared to copies, making the extra objects have a noticeable effect. In longer strings, when memory allocation is thrown into the mix, moves close the gap with aggregates when compared to copying https://quick-bench.com/q/RpjhLgamhkkOPBmHaeEeGBtVILU